# How to split the string i.e ('data+demo+on+saturday) using re in python. I want to use + for splitter but it thowing an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to split the `string` (e.g. `'data+demo+on+saturday'`) using `re` in `Python`. 
I want to use `+` for splitter but it throwing an error.

Comment: .split('+') should work

Comment: No it's not working.

Comment: it must be working. please provide a [mcve], with the code, the error, and the expected output

Comment: @RahulMisal, how come not working? what is your expected output?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-149-4783be8ea282> in <module>
----> 1 re.split('+','data+demo+on+saturday')

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in split(pattern, string, maxsplit, flags)
    211     and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element
   
error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Comment: Getting the above error.

Comment: see the answer below

Comment: Code : re.split('+','data+demo+on+saturday')

Comment: `re.split` works with a regex. `+` is a metacharacter in regular expressions. So it needs to be escaped. Try `re.split("\+")`

Comment: Don't you need to put a backslash before the '+' otherwise it modifies the previous character...

Comment: @CodeRed I want splitted array like ('data','demo','on','saturday' )

Comment: @rdas it worked with '\+'. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

By using (,), you are capturing the group, if you simply remove them you will not have this problem.

```
>>> str1 = "data demo on saturday"
>>> re.split(" +", str1)
['data', 'demo', 'on', 'saturday']
```

Comment: Use space before '+' operator as  a regex pattern for identifying space between substrings.

Comment: Use space before '+' operator as a regex pattern for identifying space between substrings.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the comments and listen to them:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'data+demo+on+saturday'
>>> re.split( r'\+', a)
['data', 'demo', 'on', 'saturday']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use '\+'

```
import re

s = "a+b+c"
s = re.split('\+', s)
print(s)
```